# Best practices when connecting to Github to automate Clone & Pull requests?

Tags: git, github, deployment, github-api

I've got a process that will be triggered automatically from another system. This process will run on a stand-alone AWS EC2 server. Each time the process is triggered, a new EC2 will be spun up and I'd like to automatically CLONE the master repo of the project to the EC2 (or maybe auto PULL it). We're trying not to overcomplicate deployment.

What is the best practices method for connecting to Github to make these requests? Since this is a process that is going to be triggered automatically on many servers, and since we have a team of devs working on it, it seems strange to use anyone's personal credentials on this automated server.

Should we simply create a new Github user that is just for this purpose? Is there a smarter more "correct" connection method to do this? I realize there are myriad container systems, deployment systems, etc. etc., but the correct way to connect to Github still remains a question.

Comment: You should be able to use GitHub Apps for that: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/